# Serialize all Instant fields through the project to only seconds value

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, java-8, jackson

I am trying to Serialize all Instant fields in all dto's, for frontend side, to seconds values (not a milliseconds or seconds.nanoseconds). I am using Spring Boot and my ObjectMapper bean contains the next line

```
.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
```

so, for now Instant fields come to frontend as milliseconds. If i remove above "disabled" line, fields start look like this

```
1605768411.538675
```

Of course I can create my own StdSerializer and add to all Instant fields next annotation

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomStdSerializedClass.class)
```

but I want to find a solution which I'll add in one place, and it will affect all Instant fields.
Any ideas?

**UPD**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;

public class CustomInstantSerializer extends StdSerializer<Instant> {

public CustomInstantSerializer() {
    this(null);
}

public CustomInstantSerializer(Class<Instant> t) {
    super(t);
}

@Override
public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeNumber(value.getEpochSecond());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleModule` to register your custom serializer:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
   module.addSerializer(Instant.class, new MyCustomSerializer());
   mapper.registerModule(module);
   return mapper;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me! I've attached Serializer code to my question.